# how to make richtext middle verticalAlign with img?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, vertical-alignment, richtext

I have a richtext with image and text in it. I am using HTML to set the textflow like this:

`<p><img source='1,jpg'><span>some words</span></p>`

I set then `verticalAlign=middle`.
But it looks like image and words still not in middle `verticalAlign` in one line.

Hope someone can help me. Here is the **code below:**

```
    var lb:RichText = new RichText;
    var htmltext:String = "<p><img source='up.gif' width='16' height='16'></img><span fontSize='12'>7772233.34</span></p>"
    lb.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(htmltext,WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE);
    var defaultStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
    defaultStyle.setStyle("textAlign","center");
    defaultStyle.setStyle("verticalAlign","middle");
    lb.styleDeclaration = defaultStyle;
```

Comment: Can you give some code here, which u have tried?

Comment: I have add code to my post.you can check it.

Comment: Althought I don't know why this happened,I choose another way. I set the position by code use x,y width ,height etc. It looks good. Anyway thanks your guys replly.

Comment: It's because display:inline-block is not working.

Answer (score -2):

Hi please use this http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/tlf/demo/ url and get import with the textflow genereated from data source and then cross check with your textflow applied.

The below is the sample text flow with textAlign center
 sample